# Is there a way to dismiss blank kivy popup when running import command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

If I run this command in python:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
```

I get the following return:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\user123\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-12-09_10.txt
[ERROR  ] [Core        ] option --ip not recognized
Kivy Usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [OPTION...]::

            Set KIVY_NO_ARGS=1 in your environment or before you import Kivy to
            disable Kivy's argument parser.

        -h, --help
            Prints this help message.
        -d, --debug
            Shows debug log.
        -a, --auto-fullscreen
            Force 'auto' fullscreen mode (no resolution change).
            Uses your display's resolution. This is most likely what you want.
        -c, --config section:key[:value]
            Set a custom [section] key=value in the configuration object.
        -f, --fullscreen
            Force running in fullscreen mode.
        -k, --fake-fullscreen
            Force 'fake' fullscreen mode (no window border/decoration).
            Uses the resolution specified by width and height in your config.
        -w, --windowed
            Force running in a window.
        -p, --provider id:provider[,options]
            Add an input provider (eg: ccvtable1:tuio,192.168.0.1:3333).
        -m mod, --module=mod
            Activate a module (use "list" to get a list of available modules).
        -r, --rotation
            Rotate the window's contents (0, 90, 180, 270).
        -s, --save
            Save current Kivy configuration.
        --size=640x480
            Size of window geometry.
        --dpi=96
            Manually overload the Window DPI (for testing only.)
    
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

If I run it again a blank kivy window opens up.

I want to establish the import but don't want to see the returned output from the first run or the blank window from the second run. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Okay...after some additional research I found that I add "Window.close()" after my import section that it will close the window. I would still be interested if anyone know how to prevent it from opening up in the first place as well as not seeing the output from the first run. I don't understand why I have to run the command twice in the first place.

Comment: You probably can't easily prevent it from showing, it's a design misfeature in kivy